# Adding Driver to Ubuntu Kernel

Tags: drivers, kernel, sensors

We want to integrate a light sensor driver with Ubuntu's kernel. Please advise how can we do it.

The light sensor code given [in `opt3001.c` here](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/drivers/iio/light/opt3001.c).

Comment: I don't think so..

Comment: Why? `opt3001` is a *single in-tree kernel module* and you want to *build* it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this is the mainline upstream kernel, so please have a look at [MainlineBuilds](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds), you can probably find the kernel suiting your needs here.

On ubuntu 16.04 , the default kernel (4.4) is too old for compiling this driver. But you can install a more recent kernel [HWE](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack) using this command : `sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-16.04`.

**Manual compiling, tested on 16.04 with kernel 4.10.0-35-generic**

```
mkdir opt3001 && cd opt3001
wget https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/plain/drivers/iio/light/opt3001.c
echo 'obj-$(CONFIG_OPT3001)     += opt3001.o' > Makefile
make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$(pwd) modules
```

Some packages may be necessary (`build-essential`, `linux-headers-$(uname -r)`, ...).

And you may have a look at [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/762255/454520) if you have troubles with secure boot (`insmod: ERROR: could not insert module opt3001.ko: Required key not available`).

Comment: Still I am not sure, how to proceed with UpStream Kernel... Are you sure we cannot compile this Light Sensor module separately and integrate it with Ubuntu Kernel. Something like below link
http://tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/x121.html#AEN128

Comment: When try to compile opt3001.c, it generates below error
```opt3001.c:19:26: fatal error: linux/bitops.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.```

Comment: please note I fixed the commands, but since `linux/bitops.h` is the first include, maybe `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)` should do.

Comment: it did not install anything, please find below result

`$ sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
linux-headers-4.4.0-96-generic is already the newest version (4.4.0-96.119).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  ...
  zlib1g-dev:i386
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 178 not upgraded.`

Comment: I just tested on a xubuntu 16.04 live-cd, nothing to install, works as expected. which version of ubuntu are you using? on which architecture? are you trying to cross-compile the module?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, amd64
`uname -a
Linux VirtualBox 4.4.0-96-generic #119-Ubuntu SMP Tue Sep 12 14:59:54 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: getting below error
`make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$(pwd) modules
make: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-96-generic
  CC [M]  /opt3001/opt3001.o
/opt3001/opt3001.c: In function ‘opt3001_irq:
/opt3001/opt3001.c:716:6: error: too many arguments to function ‘iio_get_time_ns’
In file included from /opt3001/opt3001.c:32:0:
include/linux/iio/iio.h:287:19: note: declared here
/opt3001/opt3001.c:722:6: error: too many arguments to function ‘iio_get_time_ns’
In file included from /opt3001/opt3001.c:32:0:
include/linux/iio/iio.h:287:19: note: declared here`

Comment: Ok, so your kernel is too old for this driver, you can either modify the driver code or install the latest HWE kernel by using `sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-16.04`, after a reboot you will be able to compile this driver (I just tested that in a VM).

Comment: Wow! thanks, I generated below files Makefile modules.order `Module.symvers opt3001.c opt3001.ko opt3001.mod.c opt3001.mod.o opt3001.o`

Add Module using below command to Kernel
`sudo modprobe --all opt3001`

please confirm that it?